# How is min and max of a section calculated in react-native-speedometer?

Tags: react-native, expo

I was looking into this  react native speedometer [library](https://github.com/pritishvaidya/react-native-speedometer)
it's fairly easy to set it up but what i am having trouble understanding is how the min and max of each section is calculated. initially I thought the maxValue is split up equally for each sections but looking at the demo they have, it seems random.

I am confused as how the range of each segment is determined?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the function they have `calculateLabelFromValue`.  You can see that it calculates what percent the current value is of the value range.

It then uses that percent to calculate the index of the label for the current speed.

For the default min and max of 100 this means that you  that speed 0-16.66 will be too slow, 16.67-33.33 will be the next label and so on.

```
function calculateLabelFromValue(value, labels, minValue, maxValue) {
  const currentValue = (value - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue);
  const currentIndex = Math.round((labels.length - 1) * currentValue);
  const label = labels[currentIndex];
  return label;
}
```